# How to disable an preloader

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an website with wordpress with theme named starbella-electronics and i want to disable the preloader.

Site:https://trofez-shop.ro/

I used custom css:

```
#preloader{ display:none !important; }
.preloader{ display:none !important; }
```

But it's not working and i don't have in settings theme to disable preloader

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below CSS.

```
.spinner-wrapper{display: none;}
```